Why is it divided into two parts in the new version of the Blazor project in abp framework?
I created a project with the new version of abp and noticed that this part has become two projects. What is the technical reason for this?

I'm not familiar with abp, but the .net 8 Blazor AutoRender mode needs the stuff that gets downloaded to the client to run in wasm in a seperate project, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0
